# Error in string replace function in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Given a string and a pattern, Replace all the continuous occurrence of pattern with a single X in the string. For a clear view see the example below.

**Input:**

```
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases.
The first line of each test case is string str.
The second line of each test case contains a string s,which is a pattern.
```

**Output:**

```
Print the modified string str.
```

**Constraints:**

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 100
1 ≤ size of str,s ≤ 1000
```

**Example:**

**Input**

```
2
abababcdefababcdab
ab
geeksforgeeks
geeks
```

**Output**

```
XcdefXcdX
XforX
```

code:-

```
n = int(raw_input())
for i in range(n):
  x=raw_input()
  y=raw_input()
  x1=x.replace(y,"X")
  x2=""
  count=0
  for i in x1:
    if i=='X':
      if count==0:
        x2+=i
        count+=1
      else:
        count+=1
        ## do nothing         
    elif i!='X':
      count=0
      x2+=i
print (x2)
```

Comment: The original string might already contain "XX", in which case you don't want to replace this by just "X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simpler answer with `regexp`

```
import re
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x = input()
    y = input()
    x1 = x.replace(y,"X")

    final = re.sub(r'(.)\1{1,}', r'\1', x1)
    print (final)
```

The regexp will replace any character `(x)` that occurs more than once

Answer (score 1):

My answer to this question , first I replace all occurnce of substring with `X` and then replace all sequent `X`'s with one `X`:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    x = input()
    y = input()
    x1 = x.replace(y,"X")
    flag = False
    new_x1 = ""
    for i in x1:
        if i == "X" and flag == False:
            flag = True
            new_x1 += i
        elif i != "X" :
            flag = False
            new_x1 += i
    print (new_x1)
```

OutPut:

```
2
abababcdefababcdab
ab
#XcdefXcdX
geeksforgeeks
geeks
#XforX
```